# C++: Patterns: which pattern is good for specific code execution depending on command line arguments

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, command-line-arguments

Having C++ console utility.
The code inside parses the command line input and depending on input invokes particular function.

I've got a big ugly parsing routine that calls global functions.

I dislike this code and want to organize this code by design pattern application.

The flow is as following:

- process command line args;
- if error occurs then report about it and exit, otherwise continue;
- call specific routine depending on what parameters were specified;

What pattern will you advise for this case?

Thank you.

Comment: The "write code so it makes sense, not conforms to a pattern" pattern.

Comment: What do you dislike about it?  I.e. what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I dislike code organization and its' procedural like.

Comment: @Peter I dislike 1 big function with switches and ifs that performs parsing. Moreover I dislike several global functions that perform activity depending on the command line.

Comment: @Peter I would like to encapsulate this code correctly. To make it more scalable. To leave the opportunity of beautiful new command line handling functions addition.

Comment: @Peter First I've thought about Observer pattern but then discovered that this pattern does not fit this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common design pattern used for something like this is the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Thank you Brady. I'll investigate this and reply.

Answer (score 1):

Not a pattern, but nevertheless I suggest to have a look at Boost.Program_options:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html

It easily adds support for command-line arguments to your application, as it does all the tedious parsing. To actually execute particular functions, you can then still have a look at patterns like the Command pattern (as suggested by @Brady).

However, please note that program_options is one of the Boost libraries that is not header only but requires compilation.

Comment: Thank you Johann! I will read the help and make my code clearer.